# Creating items with scaffolding not showing attributes after creation - Rails/Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, scaffolding

I'm relatively new to Rails. I'm trying to create an application that can allow users to create video game items and store them under their own users. I'm using the latest version of Rails and Devise.

Using scaffolding as a base, I created the Videogame model/controller within my application. After linking the video game models to the user who created them, it seems that any attributes that are entered into the creation form are not saving, or at the very least just not showing up on the videogames/index page. After trying to search around on Google and StackOverflow, I couldn't find any similar questions/guides to work with.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Any help for a Rails newbie would be greatly appreciated.

Below I've posted all files that may be relevant. Please let me know if anything else is needed. To see the whole project, see http://github.com/bmmart2/collection-manager

[Image after item creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GobeA.png)

[Index page of two created items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXYrf.png)

Here is my controller:

```
class VideogamesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_videogame, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /videogames
  # GET /videogames.json
  def index

    if user_signed_in?
        @videogame = current_user.videogames.all
    else
        redirect_to :root
    end
  end

  # GET /videogames/1
  # GET /videogames/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /videogames/new
  def new
    @videogame = current_user.videogames.new
  end

  # GET /videogames/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /videogames
  # POST /videogames.json
  def create
      @videogame = current_user.videogames.create(videogame_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @videogame.save
        format.html { redirect_to @videogame, notice: 'Videogame was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @videogame }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @videogame.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /videogames/1
  # PATCH/PUT /videogames/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @videogame.update(videogame_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @videogame, notice: 'Videogame was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @videogame }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @videogame.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /videogames/1
  # DELETE /videogames/1.json
  def destroy
    @videogame.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to videogames_url, notice: 'Videogame was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_videogame
      @videogame = Videogame.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def videogame_params
      params.require(:videogame).permit(:title, :publisher, :platform, :year, :condition, :upc)
    end
end
```

Videogame model:

```
class Videogame < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :user

attr_accessor :title, :platform, :upc, :condition, :publisher, :year

end
```

Videogame db migration file:

```
class CreateVideogames < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :videogames do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :publisher
      t.integer :condition
      t.string :platform
      t.string :year
      t.string :upc
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :videogames, :user_id
  end
end
```

add_user_refs_to_videogame migration:

```
class AddUserRefsToVideogame < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :videogames, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Edit: show view for video game

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @videogame.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Publisher:</strong>
  <%= @videogame.publisher %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Platform:</strong>
  <%= @videogame.platform %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Year:</strong>
  <%= @videogame.year %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Condition:</strong>
  <%= @videogame.condition %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Upc:</strong>
  <%= @videogame.upc %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_videogame_path(@videogame) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', videogames_path %>
```

Comment: What does your show view look like?

Comment: I've added it for you.

Comment: Did you create your user with the Devise generator?

Comment: In your controller, change `@videogame` to `@videogames`. That may help on your index view. Did you add `has_many :videogames` to your user model?

Comment: Yes, I believe we generated all necessary files, such as the various user controllers and devise views. Our authentication seems to be working properly, as when we create video game entries under a test user, they only show the created items for that user, and not for others. If you're interested in seeing the whole project, I have it at http://github.com/bmmart2/collection-manager

Comment: I did the associations. Ill try changing the controller and see what happens. Thanks for your help so far!
edit: Did not seem to change anything, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `attr_accessor` line in your `videogame.rb` file is causing the problem. Try deleting it and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you! That solved it perfectly. I had a feeling it would be a simple fix. Do you happen to know why the attr_accessor is causing this?